# VS Code stopped showing suggestions for C++

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

It was working fine, until it wasn't. Not sure what happened. I was thinking may be its fault of some new include headers that had "using namespace std", but I removed that and it still wont work.
Now it wont even show suggesting for basic std containers. I tried pressing ctrl + space, and it says "no suggestions found".

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that I have stuck icon in bottom right corner of VS Code that was saying "Updating IntellISense". Googled on that, as it happens some people also were having similar issue. Apparently intelisense were stuck parsing big folder, and after I removed second * from

```
"includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
```

and restarted Studio it begun showing suggestions again.